# Django admin page style

Tags: python, django, django-admin

im new to django, i created a superuser for the admin page and i installed bootstrap3 as well and put it in the installed app section. My admin page however has no style compared to the tutorial im using
I have bootstrap3 installed and put it in settings.py section. if you need more info you can ask, im new to stack overflow as well

[image: link to the image/screenshot]

Comment: can you show me your setting.py file code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stylesheet (static file) didn't load. To fix this, you need to collect static files. More about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#deployment).

> Deployment
>
> ---
>
> django.contrib.staticfiles provides a convenience management command for gathering static files in a single directory so you can serve them easily.
>
> 1. Set the STATIC_ROOT setting to the directory from which you’d like to serve these files, for example:
>    `STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"`
> 2. Run the collectstatic management command:
>    `$ python manage.py collectstatic`
>    This will copy all files from your static folders into the STATIC_ROOT directory.
> 3. Use a web server of your choice to serve the files. Deploying static files covers some common deployment strategies for static files.